# Why did Microsoft Defender detect this simple and harmless program as a "Severe" threat?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

I wrote the following program in C to test how the Windows API function [`PathCchRemoveExtension`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchremoveextension) works:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <pathcch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "pathcch.lib")

int __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    wchar_t fileName[MAX_PATH], fileNameNoExt[MAX_PATH];

    StringCchCopyW(fileName, MAX_PATH, L"C:\\DOS\\COMMAND.COM");
    StringCchCopyW(fileNameNoExt, MAX_PATH, fileName);
    PathCchRemoveExtension(fileNameNoExt, MAX_PATH);
    wprintf(L"%s => %s\n", fileName, fileNameNoExt);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it on the command line with "`cl extremove_test.c`" (no other arguments/optimizations) and Windows Defender immediately flags this program as a "Severe" threat and quarantines it when I try to run it:

[image: Error I receive immediately after I compile this]

I am on Windows 10 Pro x64 2004 Edition and on the most recent version of Windows Defender definitions (1.327.634.0 according to my Settings app)

Compiler verison is 19.27.29112 for x86

Why might a program this simple be getting detected as a "Severe" threat??

Comment: It’s likely going to be impossible for anyone here to explain the behavior, so the only thing you can do, is submit the false positive with a sample and hope update their signature

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it looked at DOS (totally insecure) and trapped it.

I had an early version of Sync Back Pro (greater than 5 year ago version) that caused Windows Defender to trap in the same way. I have current version so I allowed WD to delete it. Sync Back Pro calls outside its program to get the other files to sync.

Can you use a different approach than DOS?